# Get uploaded file name doesn't work / PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I have the following PHP/ HTML code:

```
   <?php    
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
        {
           $file_name = "../images/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];}
           echo $file_name; 
   ?>

   <form name="updateArticle" method="post">
   <div class="custom_file_upload">
          <input type="text" class="file" name="file_info" id="file_info" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $image_name;?>">
          <div class="file_upload">
                <input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file" onchange="name_change()" id="file">
         </div>
   </div>
```

The problem here is that I can't get the value of `$_FILES["file"]["name"]`

Why and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your form hasn't specified the `multipart/form-data` for file uploads

change your form and set the proper `enctype`

```
<form name="updateArticle" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```